# Passing in a Priority Queue by reference

Tags: c++, queue, pass-by-reference, priority-queue

I have a vector of priority queues of Objects with a custom comparator in my main.cpp. I have multiple functions that need the priority queue and which should modify the priority queue. What is the correct way to go about passing in a priority queue by reference? Would it be using pointers? I am extremely confused about how to go about this.

In my main I declare my priority queue like:
The type is of Order 
`vector<priority_queue<Order, vector<Order>, compLower> >  buy_orders (num_equities);`

I call a function makeTransaction which only deal with the individual priority queues:

`makeTransaction(equity_id, buy_orders[equity_id]);`

However, when I call this function and later try to access `buy_orders`, nothing changes. How can I pass it by reference so `makeTransaction` can make the necessary changes to `buy_orders`?

Also, how would I appropriately declare the makeTransaction function?

Comment: Show us some code please. Make discussions easier.

Comment: You said " passing in a priority queue by reference " and then quickly talked about pointers. Why not just pass by reference ? And then yes, show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
void my_function(std::priority_queue<MyObject>& q)
{
  while(q.size() >= 10)
  {
    MyObject& o = q.top();
    // Do something with o
    q.pop();
  }
}

// Call the function :
std::priority_queue<MyObject> my_queue;
// fill the queue
my_function(my_queue); // Here, my_queue will be modified
```